# Any way to keep variables grouped by group_by?

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, grouping, tidyverse

I have a data frame with a Location column and a County column showing data for different locations with a group of counties. I am grouping by the County column for another calculation, but I want to retain a way to see what locations are included in each County. Is that possible?

Here's a sample of what the original data looks like:

```
location   county   x   y
hend       hender   2   10
alam       alam     0   5
alex       alam     4   3
alleg      allegy   6   1
ann        hender   9   0
```

Here's what I changed it too:

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(county) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(x + y))

county   total
hender   17
alam     12
allegy   7
```

Again, not sure if this is possible, but I would ideally like a third column (we'll call this allloc) showing the locations in each county, comma-separated if possible. Something like this:

```
county   total   allloc
hender   17      hend, ann
alam     12      alam, alex
allegy   7       alleg
```

I tried using summarize and paste, mutate and paste and coalesce without success.

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(county) %>%
  summarise(allloc = paste(location))

df <- df %>%
  group_by(county) %>%
  mutate(allloc = paste(location))

df <- df %>%
  group_by(county) %>%
  mutate(allloc = coalesce(df$location))
```

Any thoughts?

(Last but not least, here's some reproducible code):

```
df <- data.frame(location = c("hend", "alam", "alex", "alleg", "ann"), county = c("hender", "alam", "alam", "allegy", "hender"), x = c(2, 0 , 4, 6, 9), y = c(10, 5, 3, 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create multiple columns in `summarise` :

```
library(dplyr)

result <- df %>%
           group_by(county) %>%
           summarise(total = sum(x + y), 
                     allloc = toString(location))
                     #Same as :
                     #allloc = paste0(location, collapse = ','))
result

#  county total allloc    
#  <chr>  <dbl> <chr>     
#1 alam      12 alam, alex
#2 allegy     7 alleg     
#3 hender    21 hend, ann
```

Answer (score 3):

While `toString` is good for summary information, if you ever need to re-extract the different locations, I feel it is better (well, more *general*) to store the data as list-columns instead of strings. (The latter requires re-parsing them to split them, which can be simple with `strsplit` until there are embedded commas or token-splitters within the actual data.)

```r
results <- df %>%
  group_by(county) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(x + y), allloc = list(location) )
results
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   county total allloc   
#   <chr>  <int> <list>   
# 1 alam      12 <chr [2]>
# 2 allegy     7 <chr [1]>
# 3 hender    21 <chr [2]>
```

You can see what is happening under the hood a little with `str` on that:

```r
str(results)
# tibble [3 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#  $ county: chr [1:3] "alam" "allegy" "hender"
#  $ total : int [1:3] 12 7 21
#  $ allloc:List of 3
#   ..$ : chr [1:2] "alam" "alex"
#   ..$ : chr "alleg"
#   ..$ : chr [1:2] "hend" "ann"
```

showing that `allloc` is showing a list, length 3, with variable lists of character strings.

Times when this will be useful/justified:

- you have follow-on processing on the `location` data that prefers to keep it in vectors of some length (for each `county`); ***or***
- you will want to reconstitute/lengthen the data, which is really just a special case of the previous bullet;

Times when this is not desired:

- when your reason for creating `allloc` is purely for visual reporting; ***and***
- the original data never has embedded commas.